# Replace a character with another character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, char, ascii

I have a table with certain rows containing `Œ` in the text and I want to find and replace them with `£` but it is finding text with OE as well which I don't want it to find.

At the moment I've stripped everything back and I'm just trying to find the position of the `Œ` in a string of characters.

I've tried the following 3 lines but all return the same result.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(140), '1234OE7ŒA9')

SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(140), '1234OE7ŒA9' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI )

SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(140), cast('1234OE7Œ9' as varchar(20)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI)
```

All the results above return 5 which is the start position of OE but I want it to only find records which contain `Œ` which is at position 8 in the string. Char 140 is `Œ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your first statement:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(140), '1234OE7ŒA9')
```

on a database with collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`: it returned 8.

So probably this statement should work:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(140), '1234OE7ŒA9' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
```

results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/909742/andrea  yes that worked :-)